# How can I find all unused methods & variables of my project in the XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to find all unused methods, variables and code into an old iOS project. Is it possible to find?

Comment: Solution found here: [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-can-i-find-all-unused-methods-variables-of-my-project-in-the-xcode/52575)
[Periphery](https://github.com/peripheryapp/periphery)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script to find unused Swift functions and variables at a specified path.
https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/swift-scripts